# How to improve SpecFlow intellisense in Visual Studio

Tags: visualstudio, specflow

I'm using SpecFlow to write automated test cases for a project. I'm writing them in Visual Studio 2013 It's cool and the intellisense works, but I have some issues with it:

1. Is it possible to limit the number of command examples intellisense shows? I don't need 10 examples for one common command, a couple would be enough, they take up too much space.
2. Is it possible to have a scrollbar for the intellisense popup? Currently there isn't one, and because of the many examples I can't see what other commands are available.

It looks like the popup has been cut off and it is supposed to have a scrollbar (I cropped the right side of it, but the height is shown in full):

[image: SpecFlow Intellisense]

Comment: Situation is still the same with VS 2015 and latest SpecFlow extension.